# Expanding log problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, logarithms, radicals, absolute-value

I found this site with online problems and answers. 
https://courses.lumenlearning.com/waymakercollegealgebra/chapter/expand-and-condense-logarithms/

I've tried several problems and my answer is always wrong.

I've added two screenshots: 
1) the problem and the answer according to the site

[image]

2) my work and answer

[image]

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?
I don't understand why the denominator disappears.

Thanks

Comment: You should have $\frac{1}{2}\ln (y + 7) - \ln (y + 7) = -\frac{1}{2} \ln (y + 7)$ in your final step.

Comment: Your solution is correct. It seems there is a typo in your source. As noticed it is important recognize that we are implicitly assuming $x>7$.

Comment: @LiesVanRompaey Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the domain gives $y>7$ and
$$\ln\frac{\sqrt{(y^2-49)(y+8)^6}}{y+7}=\ln\frac{\sqrt{y-7}|y+8|^3}{\sqrt{y+7}}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(y-7)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y+7)+3\ln|y+8|=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(y-7)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y+7)+3\ln(y+8).$$

Comment: I thought exactly to the same explanation...the key point indeed is that $x>7$ :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for the definition of the given expression that $y>7$ we can avoid absolute values when extracting from square roots since all factors are positive and your result appears to be correct.